# HttpClientFactory throwing 500 errors for valid API

Tags: c#, webapi, httpclientfactory

I'm in the process of rewriting a legacy application using Dapper, WebAPI and HttpClientFactory to make DB calls. My development time has drastically been slowed down because I'm having to debug frequent 500 errors and I've been unable to understand what's causing them.

For example, I can get a list of events using this code:

```
return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Event>>
    (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/Event/GetEvents"), 
        new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

However, this code- which is nearly identical to what I'm using to return the list of events- produces a 500 error:

```
return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Event>
    (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/Event/GetEventDetail/{eventId}"), 
        new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

I broke that into two lines and found that this works:

```
var response = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/Event/GetEventDetail/{eventId}");
return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Event>(response);
```

Can anyone help me make sense of what's causing the error with the one-line solution?

Comment: 500 error means, the issue is at the server end. Is there any other information you get in the response content. That may (or may not) help you to understand what's the issue at server. If the API is the third party API then you can report the issue to them. If the API is developed by you then you can fix it yourself. But first you need to know what's the issue with the server.

Comment: The exact error is "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)". This is a WebAPI project I created. It seems like it's not the API itself that's the problem - I have tested it in Swagger and it works if I use that two-line method to call it - I just can't figure out why calling it as shown in the one-line example above is resulting in the error.